# ODE Problem - how to proceed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this ODE:

$\dot{x}(t+x^2) = x$

...using this hint:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dx}}$.

I'm not entirely sure what this hint even means but I am guessing it has something to do with the inverse function. I would appreciate some guidance on the matter or at least an explanation of what this hint is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you look for $t$ as a function of $x$m then $$
\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{t+x^2}x
= \frac tx + x
$$
whose general solution is $$
t(x) = Cx + x^2
$$
[via variation a the constant: solution of $\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac tx$ is
$t(x) = Cx$, and variation a the constant gives $xC'(x) = x$ giving $
C(x) = x $ as a particular solution].

Now solve the equation in $x(t)$.

Suppose for example an initial condition $x(0) = x_0$.

$$
0 = t(x_0) = Cx_0 + x_0^2
$$
has two solutions: $x_0 = 0$ leads to the solution, otherwise $C = -x_0$ and
$$
t = -x_0x(t) + x(t)^2
$$
that is, $$
x(t) = \frac 12 (x_0 +\sqrt{x_0^2 + 4t})
$$ (the choice is done thanks to the initial condition).

Answer (score 0):

$\dot{x}(t+x^2) = x$

$\frac{dx}{dt}(t+x^2) = x$

$tdx+x^2{dx}= xdt$

$tdx-xdt=-x^2{dt}$

$\frac{xdt-tdx}{x^2}=dx$

$d(\frac{t}{x})=dx$

$\int d(\frac{t}{x})=\int dx$

$\frac{t}{x}=x+C$

$t=x^2+Cx$ we can write this in $x^2+Cx-t=0$ form.Then we can solve this as quadratic equation.So

$D=C^2+4t$  then  $x=\frac{-C\pm \sqrt{C^2+4t}}{2}=-\frac{C}{2} \pm$ $\sqrt{(\frac{C}{2})^2+t^2}$

Finally solution of the equation is $x=-\frac{C}{2} \pm$ $\sqrt{(\frac{C}{2})^2+t^2}$

Note. $C$ is invariable